# How to parse a URL using Ruby

Tags: ruby

*Hi 
how i print*

```
http://site.tf/home/
```

from

```
http://site.tf/home/index.php?id=12
```

using ruby parse url

Comment: You want to print `http://site.tf/home/` or just `site.tf/home/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://site.tf/home/index.php?id=12')
"#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}/#{uri.path.split('/')[1]}"
#=> "http://site.tf/home/"
```

Didn't tested though.I guess it should work fine

**Update**

If you want just `site.tf`,just do like this

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://site.tf/home/index.php?id=12')
uri.host.split('/').first
#=> "site.tf"
```

Comment: Your first code snippet doesn't work... should be `"#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}/#{uri.path.split('/')[1]}"`

Comment: @UriAgassi Thanks!Updated :) I just learning the Ruby now.Forgive my wrong answer.